# TinyMCE change DIV id, somehow

Tags: php, jquery, tinymce

I need to make it easier for employees to change the ID tag of divs that are loaded in the TinyMCE (4) textarea. Since the attribute editor is removed in version 4 (It used to be available in version 3)...
So i decided to make a workaround by using a click event on each element with the following code:

```
setup : function(ed) {
    ed.on('click', function(e) {
        var element = $(e.target);
        console.log(element.prop("id"));
        if(e.target.nodeName == 'DIV'){
            var target = e.target;
            $("#artnr").val(target.id);
            var dialog = $(".dialog").dialog("open");
            alert(target);
            alert(target.id);
            console.log(target);
            dialog.find("form").bind("submit", function(ev){
                alert("Target" + $(target).prop("id"));
                $(target).prop("id", $("#artnr").val().toLowerCase());
                alert("Target" + $(target).prop("id"));
                $(target).append("<span>" + $("#artnr").val().toLowerCase() + "</span>");
                dialog.dialog("close");
                ev.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    });
},
```

You might notice there's a lot of alerts. Thats because this causes a problem. The first div I click in the tinymce editor works fine, the id. But as soon as i change the second ID it changes the first as well. 
It is possible for the elements in the TinyMCE that they have the same ID. This shouldn't matter though, since the ID gets changed, right?

Also, I searched a lot to find a replacement for the attribute editor, if someone knows a replacement?

Comment: You're binding a submit event listener inside a handler that will be called more than once. You'll have to remove previously bound event listeners, because ATM, every handler/callback has its own scope, and its own reference to `target`. Alternatively, use `target` in a closure, and reassign it every time, so that `target` is shared, but that's just messy

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Have I been understanding the E in the function() wrong? Because I believed it assigned the currently clicked target to this.

Comment: No, but you're creating a local variable `var target`, and in the click callback, you're binding a listener (`dialog.find('form').bind('submit', function(){});`, who's handler is accessing that `target` variable, but the listener is never unbound. So on submit, each handler has its own `target` var that it'll use, each of these vars referencing a different div... hence, any div that has been processed will change

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, unbinding the submit would fix the problem then i assume, is that what you mean with "use target in a closure"?

Comment: wrap your `tinymce.init()` call in an IFFE where `target` is declared (`(function(){ var target; tinymce.init({});}());`, remove the `var` inside your current code, to use the outer (closure) `target` var, which will then be shared by all handlers, so they all reference the same element